# How do I set up VS Code to put JavaScript curly braces on a new line?

Tags: javascript, formatting, code-formatting, visual-studio-code

Let's say I type in the following code and format it.

```
if (condition) { /* Hello! */ }
```

If this is C# code, it is formatted like this:

```
if (condition)
{
    // Hello!
}
```

If it is JavaScript, VSCode formats it like this:

```
if (condition) {
    // Hello!
}
```

So how can I use the first formatting style (curly braces on new lines) for all languages? I can't find a setting or something similar. Suggestions?

Comment: Curly brace on the next line has side-effects in the Javascript, it should be on the same line, according to me the setting for formatting the code should be as it is

Comment: @Tushar really? I thought it's just formatting. Can you reference some articles or give a simple example?

Comment: It's because semicolon are not mandatory in JS so if you put your curly brace in the next line, how the interpreter will know if you forgot the semicolon or if you are still in the same statement in some ambiguous cases? [source](http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/).

Comment: @ShanShan Is this ECMA standart or just compiler specific?

Comment: @M.Fatih Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion can cause the problems when you put the `{` on next line. The famous example is `return {a: 'b'};`, here `{` is on the next line of `return`. when semicolon is added the same statement is treated as `return;` and next line `{..` which results in returning `undefined` when you expect object, read more  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi and http://jamesallardice.com/understanding-automatic-semi-colon-insertion-in-javascript/

Comment: @M.Fatih It's in the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9

Comment: Formatting configuration is a personal like, some like to put the open braces on a new line, other like to put them on the same line. Telling something like "in Javascript putting open braces on the same line has side effect" isn't correct. The only place there it's mandatory to put the open-braces on the same line is in a "return { ..." statement. In all other cases it's just fine. In codding standards you can choice your on style, JUST BE CONSIST, if you selected to put your open-braces on a new line, be consist in your entire 
 project.

Comment: @Shanoor I think there's something wrong with encosia (I wasn't able to get to it), but the article can be found on the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160421051556/http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/)

Comment: You should not work against the result of `dartfmt` on your code.  Formatting in Dart is *not* a personal choice.

Comment: Any updates? How can I achieve the result for C#?

Comment: I've post on my blog the solution for this issue. 
Basically, only on save e on paste the format will work. On type won't this is an issue open on vscode https://amandamata.github.io/curly-brace

Comment: I've post on my blog the solution for this issue. Basically, only on save e on paste the format will work. On type won't this is an issue open on vscode amandamata.github.io/curly-brace

Answer (score 96):

Follow the steps below to make **Visual Studio Code** format opening curly braces on a new line for **Java Script** and **Type Script**.

In **Visual Studio Code (v1.20.0)**

1. Go to File\Preferences\Settings
2. Add the following lines in '**User Settings**' (in the right side pane)

   ```
   "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true, 
   "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,

   "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
   "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
   ```
3. Save '**User Settings**' and you are done!

Comment: The latest version of VS code doesn't even require typing! The design is now akin to about:config in browsers

Comment: The settings help but it's not perfect, it seems like it gets the first control statement of a given block fine, but it misses the occasional `else`, and `else if`, `catch`, etc. Strange.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do this for PowerShell?

Comment: What about `C#`? or `csharp`? There's no format options like above...

Comment: I would also like to add a reference to link https://robertwray.co.uk/blog/braces-on-new-lines-in-visual-studio-code that helped me. Might help somebody else.

Comment: what if I like the javascript style and want c++ to use that insted. Is there any settings for that.?

Comment: I added an answer that explains how to get the "javascript style" (at least in c#)

Comment: Anyway to do this in IntelliJ

Comment: @HiTech: If you have the MS PowerShell extension installed go to `File > Preferences` (or use hotkey `Ctrl+,`) to open the settings then type "open brace" in the settings search bar.  There are 5 PowerShell settings related to braces, including `PowerShell > Code Formatting: Open Brace on Same Line`.  Turn that option off.

Answer (score 38):

Go to File\Preferences\Settings and search for 'brace'.

Enable the settings illustrated below.

This allows me to auto-format code with curly braces on the following line for function definitions and control blocks.

[image: File\Preferences\Settings]

Tested with Visual Studio Code 1.30.2

Comment: Where's `csharp`? This is only half the answer.

Comment: searching for 'curly'  gives 0 results, 'brace' gives results

Answer (score 10):

Those who need the solution for **PHP**, you need to install `PHP Intelephense`  Extension and update the `settings.json` file.

```
"intelephense.format.braces": "k&r"
```

By default it was `psr12`.

Answer (score 6):

By default VS code don't support customization in formatting. But you could do your format customization using ***js-beautify*** extension. You can find the free version on VS code Marketplace (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify).

For your requirement of **curly braces on new line** can be setup by creating a '**.jsbeautifyrc**' config file on your project root folder and define a following line.

```
{
     "brace_style": "expand"
}
```

For more formatting options you can find from the following link:
https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/blob/master/Settings.md

Answer (score 4):

VSCode>File>Preferences>Settings> <type "brace" (without quotas)>
and uncheck CSharpFixFormat>Style>Braces>On Same Line
[image]

Comment: There is no `CSharpFixFormat`. What extensions did you install?

Answer (score 3):

C_Cpp: Clang_format_fallback Style

Google

Comment: Please provide more details how this helps answer?

Comment: `C_Cpp: Clang_format_fallback Style`  setting set as `Google` will make the open curly brace at the end of the last line of the function declaration, not the start of the next line. if it is set as `Visual Studio`, braces will be put on a new line. 

See: [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Function_Declarations_and_Definitions)

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines in **settings.json** file, open it by type **ctrl+,**

```
  // Brackets on a new line
  "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
  "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
  "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
  "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
```

Or from the **settings** search for **function new line** and check the two boxes, open it by type **ctrl+shift+p** and search for **open
settings (json)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference: if it is for Java. File\preferences\settings
Extensions\Java\Code Generation: Use Blocks.[image: Java Code Blocks]

Comment: What about getting the opening brace on a new line for everything, not just after if statements?

Answer (score 1):

In 2021 the default behavior seems to be what OP wanted. To get curly braces on same line in c# (vscode 1.63 with omnisharp) you have to create a omnisharp.json file in project root with proper settings as described at https://nosuchstudio.medium.com/formatting-curly-braces-on-the-same-line-in-c-in-vscode-c4937e1c215f . e.g.

```
{
"FormattingOptions": {
    "NewLinesForBracesInLambdaExpressionBody": false,
    "NewLinesForBracesInAnonymousMethods": false,
    "NewLinesForBracesInAnonymousTypes": false,
    "NewLinesForBracesInControlBlocks": false,
    "NewLinesForBracesInTypes": false,
    "NewLinesForBracesInMethods": false,
    "NewLinesForBracesInProperties": false,
    "NewLinesForBracesInObjectCollectionArrayInitializers": false,
    "NewLinesForBracesInAccessors": false,
    "NewLineForElse": false,
    "NewLineForCatch": false,
    "NewLineForFinally": false
}

}
```

Comment: I don't understand where you put this file?

Answer (score 0):

**Found a fix for C#!**
Download [C# Curly Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ironcutter24.cscurlyformatter) extension by Ironcutter24. Done! Now all your braces will move to a new line. Clean and beautiful.

Answer (score -8):

The following instruction apply to VS Pro 2012...

1. On the menu bar choose Tools.
2. Choose Options...
3. Expand the Text Editor list.
4. Expand the JavaScript list.
5. Expand the Formatting list.
6. Choose New Lines.
7. Choose Place open brace on new line for control blocks.

I hope this is helpful.  Feel free to reply if you have any questions.

Comment: Err... I tagged question on vscode. Not asking for Visual Studio Community/Professional/Ultimate etc. ;) ([See VSCode here](https://code.visualstudio.com/))

Comment: This is not an answer to a Visual Studio Code question; Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are totally different.