# How to change code formatting in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-code

Hi I'm using VS Code for TypeScript and JavaScript.
Standart autoformat create code like this

```
if(ind){
 // code
}
```

but I don't like this :), how to set autoformat as

```
if(ind)
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: try using => Ctrl + K + D

Comment: Ctr + K + D is for Visual Studio. In Visual Studio Code it's Alt/Option+ Shift + F. But this will not change how Visual Studio Code formats brackets. I do not think it's possible.

Comment: Semi duplicate of this question, but the other way around: [How do I set up VSCode to put curly braces on a new line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900921/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-put-curly-braces-on-a-new-line) Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it's possible to specify formatting options in VSCode at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `TypeScript` in `settings.json`

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
    "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
    "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true
}
```

and autoformat!

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: The same applies for javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible with VsCode, but there is [an issue tracking the problem](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1533) and [here's the actual code fix](https://github.com/SofianHn/vscode/commit/9d85038e9ac54954bc241792d870aec2f5b7f6e0).

Keep in mind that this is from the development branch, so the behavior and settings may change, but I believe the settings you will want are:

`javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks`
and/or
`javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions`

This feature should make it into an official release shortly, but if you want the try out bleeding edge features you can always [build VsCode from the source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#build-and-run-from-source).

Comment: Is this still the case? seems like adding these lines to my user settings don't do anything