# How to format braces in Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I like to see my code like this

```
if(a == b)
{
    // My Code
}

public void method_name(parameter list)
{
    //My Code
}
```

not like this

```
if(a == b){
    // My Code
}

public void method_name(parameter list){
        //My Code
}
```

But i can't figure out how to do that in vs code automatically or using code formating

using manual strategy is very painful

I look for many solutions but can't figure out one

also installed **Visual Studio Code Format** extension
but don't know how to set that up

Comment: Have you tried using Alt+Shift+F?

Comment: yeah, but i want to change to format style. this key is for formatting code in a defined style

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35939427/11683

Comment: @GSerg thanks. but can i use this for all languages. cause i write code maximum time on c,c++,c#,python,java. sorry i am a student. so , i had to do those. that solution is for typescript and javascipt

Comment: Alt+Shift+F formats code like your preferred method for me when a file has the extension `cs`. Is it not working for any language?

Comment: @DanielGale sorry, i don't know, why it's not working for me

Comment: @DanielGale for me Alt+Shift+F formats the code to reverse that i want to

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio select Tools menu option, then "Options". 
From there find: Text Editor, then find your associated language. C#, etc.
Under "Formatting" there is an option for "Spacing". You can tweak as needed.