# Unexpected Indentation of Nested Opening Brackets

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, js-beautify

EDIT: I don't want to put opening curly brackets on a separate line, in general. I simply want to do so in this case where two opening brackets are on the same line. ESLint does it correctly but Beautify does not, but ESLint is only for inline Javascript.

I'm using the Beautify extension in VSCode to try to format this chunk of inline javascript as follows:

```
    const dogs = [
        {
            name: 'Snickers',
            age: 2,
        },
        {
            name: 'Hugo',
            age: 2,
        },
        {
            name: 'Sunny',
            age: 2,
        },
    ];
```

Instead, it does this:

```
    const dogs = [{
            name: 'Snickers',
            age: 2,
        },
        {
            name: 'Hugo',
            age: 2,
        },
        {
            name: 'Sunny',
            age: 2,
        },
    ];
```

As you can see, it puts the opening square and curly brackets on the same line. Is there a rule (in .jsbeautifyrc) to force the desired behavior or is this a bug in js-beautify?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up VSCode to put curly braces on a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900921/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-put-curly-braces-on-a-new-line)

Comment: See my EDIT. I only want these nested opening brackets such as this separated onto separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try paste this rule in your `.jsbeautifyrc`

```
    {
        "js": {
            "brace_style": "expand"
        }
    }
```

---

Also you can try this extension too: [Visual Studio Code Format](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryannaddy.vscode-format)

Comment: See my edit. This is inline javascript and I don't want curly brackets in general on a separate line.

Answer (score 1):

Prettier is also used for formatting the code in VS code. This extension does not have this problem. You can try installing this extension and try once. I have checked this and did not see this issue.

Extension name: Prettier - Code formatter

Comment: Prettier doesn't have that problem but it breaks other things and uses a different configuration file with different conventions. I'd rather just fix this one thing.