# How to configure VS code when coding PHP so braces are keep on new line

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Assume I have this code where each brace is on a separate line. As soon as I save this code the code is changed by VS code so each brace is no longer on a separate line.

```
function mainEngine(string &$errmessage): void
{
    if (isFormSent()) 
    {
        if ((new User())->loginUser($_POST['username'], 
           $_POST['password'])) 
        {
            header("Location:admin.php");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $errmessage = "Felaktig användare/password";
        }
    }
}
```

//Tony

Comment: [Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/)

Comment: It's much more dificult to read the code when the braces are not on separate line. I have tried with .php_cs located in the root without success which looks like this <?php

return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
->setRules(array(
    'braces' => array(
        'position_after_anonymous_constructs' => 'next',
        'position_after_control_structures' => 'next',
    )
));

Comment: I would disagree, I find it much more anoying when the braces are all on seperate lines. It also means I cannot see as many lines of code on a screen, because half of those I can see are just `{` and `}`

Comment: I know that this is highly debated but I just want to know if i can make some settings to keep braces on separate line when I code PHP in VS code

Comment: Is there any way to make VS code to keep braces on separate line when I save the code after having done some coding for PHP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up VSCode to put curly braces on a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900921/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-put-curly-braces-on-a-new-line)

Answer (score 0):

As [M. Volf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7292139/m-volf) says:
This is the specific intelephense braces config (`k&r` type braces) on your User Settings (JSON), add this line:

```
    "intelephense.format.braces": "k&r",
```