# How to change {} in vscode auto-complete

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm new in this programming stuff so i don't really know how to describe my issue but i'm gonna try.

I starded using vscode for programming in c, i'm using the c/c++ extension there, but the {} (i don't even know it's name haha) is placed like:

```
if (a > b)
{
code;
}
```

while i wanted it to be like:

```
if (a > b){
code;
}
```

I would appreciate if you could tell me those terms, as well as recommending any place where i learn that, i'm at the really beginning so any help is great<3

Comment: The different positioning of the **braces** (aka *curly* or *squiggly brackets*) and spacing/new lines is part of a **indentation style**. *I don't know how to make Visual Studio use a specific detail in its style.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up VSCode to put curly braces on a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900921/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-put-curly-braces-on-a-new-line) --obviously you want to do the converse, but that's where the options are

Answer (score 0):

Go to File => Preferences => Settings
and then click on this icon up top.

[image: Here]

at the end of the last setting enter a comma `,` and then press enter and add this line below:

```
 "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "Google"
```

Comment: it didn't work for me :(((