# Changing bracket indentation in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, settings, brackets

As I am moving from Visual Studio to Visual Studio Code, I have noticed that the bracket indentation changes from this:

```
void hello()
{
  // code
}
```

to this:

```
void hello() {
  // code
}
```

**How can I change the bracket indentation to match the old one that Visual Studio used?** I am mainly coding in C# so it would be nice if the changes applied to that language, or if that is not possible, then the entire editor, regardless of language used

I have tried almost every solution available on the Internet. Some of them include modifying the settings.json file and making changes such as: `"editor.autoIndent": "full"`, `"editor.formatOnType": true`, and more. If you need more info, feel free to ask!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up VSCode to put curly braces on a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900921/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-put-curly-braces-on-a-new-line)